# How to get GWT CSSResource to parse not() selectors

Tags: gwt, css, cssresource

I realize that the CSS parser that GWT uses will only handle CSS2, but I am targeting iPhone Safari, so I want to be able to use some of the CSS3 stuff.  For properties, I have been fine using the `literal` function provided by GWT, but I'm having trouble with CSS3 selectors - particularly the `not()` pseudo-class.

I have a bit of CSS like this:

```
.iMore:not (.__lod ):active {
    color: #fff
}
```

When GWT loads this file as a resource, I get:

> encountered "(". Was expecting one of: "{" ","

the `literal` function works well for properties, but I tried this:

```
.iMore:literal("not (.__lod )"):active {
    color: #fff
}
```

and just got a different error message:

> encountered ""not (.__lod ):"". Was expecting one of: `<IDENT`>

I put `literal` around the whole block and the error message went away, but I don't think that will work without `@external`ing everything referenced in the selectors that use this (there are a lot of others in this file).

1. Would that even work?
2. Is there a more graceful way of doing it?

Comment: I'd understand some "cool" CSS3 like the transitions, etc. but `:not` is hardly worth the effort - because the only "elegant" way I see is just hacking the CSS parser to accept CSS3 selectors.

Comment: The problem is that I'm inheriting someone else's CSS file. I have access to edit it but I'd like to not recreate it all. What's the css2 equivalent of the above statement? I don't think there is an easy one is there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You escape the parentheses in the selector with backslashes.  So for your CSS:

```
.iMore:not \(.__lod \):active {
    color: #fff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had given up on this long ago so I don't have the code to test it out.

Comment: Oh well.  It's there for posterity :-)

Comment: +1 This works. It's worth noting that even more gnarly not() selectors can be escaped using enough backslashes. For example, `not([type="search"])` becomes `not\(\[type\=\"search\"\]\)`.

Comment: One other note: The space before the escaped closing parenthesis is important. `.iMore:not\(.__lod\)` will currently result in the error "[ERROR] The following unobfuscated classes were present in a strict CssResource:
[ERROR] __lod\\)" http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4422#c14